# Result about limaçon

Tags: polar-coordinates

Wikipedia's ["Limaçon" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on#Form) gives the following information about the polar curve $r=b+a\cos(\theta)$:

- When $b>a$, the limaçon is a simple closed curve. However, the origin satisfies [the Cartesian translation of the equation], so the graph of this equation has an acnode or isolated point.
- When $b>2a$, the area bounded by the curve is convex, and when ${\displaystyle a<b<2a}$, the curve has an indentation bounded by two inflection points. At ${\displaystyle b=2a}$, the point ${\displaystyle (-a,0)}$ is a point of 0 curvature.
- As $b$ is decreased relative to $a$, the indentation becomes more pronounced until, at $b=a$, the curve becomes a cardioid, and the indentation becomes a cusp. For $0<b<a$, the cusp expands to an inner loop, and the curve crosses itself at the origin. As $b$ approaches $0$, the loop fills up the outer curve and, in the limit, the limaçon becomes a circle traversed twice.

> I'm familiar with polar curves and some of its special cases,however these results about Limaçon is new to me and I don't know hoe to prove them (notice that I'm not asking about the formula of a Limaçon itself).

Comment: I think we need to edit your Q, because in Wikipedia I can see $r=b+a\cos(\theta)$...

Comment: *"How we can prove them? Where does that come from?"* Just "graph and observe" would seem to cover much of this. (Thinking about the Cartesian graph of $y=a+b\cos x$ also helps.) What exactly do you want proven? ... and what exactly is the "famous result" mentioned in the title?

Comment: @ Blue,good point,I've never even thought about that,so every problem in mathematics that seems true intuitively, should be accepted? it's like we say "well this is true, because this is what I'm seeing,so no proof is needed"

Comment: @ blue,everything is clear,however if you think it's not,then feel free to edit it to make it possible to read.

Comment: @number: Again, it would be helpful if you said exactly what you want proven. If you want proof that $b>a(>0)$ leads the polar graph of $r=b+a\cos\theta$ (as Wikipedia writes it) to be a "simple closed curve"? Well, since $\cos\theta$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$, the value of $b+a\cos\theta$ oscillates between $b-a$ and $b+a$; when $b>a>0$, this value is strictly positive, so the polar graph is never in danger of self-intersecting (so, it's "simple"), and the periodic nature of $\cos\theta$ guarantees that the graph is a loop (hence "closed"). Is that what you want?

Comment: @number: In any case, you should say something about what you know about this problem, and/or the nature of polar graphs in general, and/or what about this particular graph is giving you trouble. This will help answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (Is my description above too basic? too advanced? about right?) ... I'm still wondering: of the multiple facts about the curve you've mentioned, what's the "famous result"?

Comment: @number: Post-edit, I guess none of the results are "famous". :) Okay, so I'll ask this instead: When you write *"Where does that come from?"* are you asking for how the equation for the limaçon is derived? (Here again, it would be helpful to know some of your background: How familiar are you with translating the geometric descriptions (eg, circles rolling on circles) into polar equations?) Or, are you taking the polar equation as the starting point of discussion and wondering how the stated properties arise?

Comment: @Blue,I've edited,I hope it's clear now ,and thanks for your comments.